# Why is passing (!NULL) in if-else condition true in C?

Tags: c, if-statement, null

In these lines of code,

```
void main()
{
   if(!NULL)
     {
       printf("one.");
     }
   else
     {
       printf("two");
     }
}
```

the output is one.  Why is that? Why is `!NULL` true?

Answer (score 8):

From C Standard#6.3.2.3p3 *[emphasis added]*

> 3 An integer constant expression **with the value 0**, or such an expression cast to type `void *`, is called a **null pointer constant**.<sup>66)</sup> If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.
>
> ....
> ....
>
> <sup>66)</sup> The macro **NULL** is defined in `<stddef.h>` (and other headers) **as a null pointer constant**; see 7.19.

From C Standard#6.5.3.3p5

> 5 The result of the logical negation operator ! is 0 if the value of its operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand compares equal to 0. The result has type int. The expression !E is equivalent to (0==E).

So, this statement

```
if(!NULL)
```

is equivalent to

```
if (0==NULL)
```

`0==NULL` is evaluated to `true`. Hence, you are getting output `one`.

---

Additional:

The `void` return type of `main()` is not as per standard. Instead, you should use `int` as return type of `main()`.

Answer (score 3):

NULL is the pointer equivalent of 0. 0 is false in C and any other non-zero value is positive.

Hence if !(not operator) is applied to NULL(false), it implies that !NULL is true.

So the if condition is satisfied as true and 'one.' is printed.

Answer (score 2):

In short :-

According to **C language** standards ,

> **Non-Zero** value is equivalent to **TRUE**
>
> **Zero** & **NULL** are equivalent to **FALSE**

Hence, **(! NULL)** is equivalent to **TRUE**. So, **if** block is executing and **one.** is printed.